# Random Values, SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am getting random values starting with B@. I am not sure about what is happening
in my code, and I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me figure out what is going on and would greatly appreciate it if you could give me a solution. Here is the code:

to read:

```
     public List displayData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context
            .MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String, ?> allMap = sharedPref.getAll();
    all = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allMap.entrySet()) {
        all.add(entry.getKey().toString() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
    }
    return all;
}
```

to save:

```
private void save(String type, String content){
    editor.putString(type.getBytes().toString(), content.getBytes().toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

to delete:

```
private void delete(String key){
    editor.remove(key);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
editor.putString(type.getBytes().toString(), content.getBytes().toString());
```

with:

```
editor.putString(type, content);
```

Comment: It worked, but when I try to edit the EditText, the values in the EditText wouldn't change. @CommonsWare